# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't goes next or previous in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I'm using React Next.js and Bootstrap for a project. I needed to use Bootstrap's Carousel on the Homepage. Everything turns out fine except it doesn't slide left or right (also with indicator according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators ). Here's the code.

I'm using "bootstrap": "^5.0.2" with Next.js and I've made sure to import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; in the _app.tsx file

index.tsx

```
<main className="home-layout">
        <div>
          <MyCarousel/>
        </div>
</main>
```

MyCarousel.tsx

```
export const MyCarousel = () => {
  return (
    <div className="my-2">
      <h2>Sample Carousel</h2>
      <div
        className="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
        id="myCarousel"
      >
        <div className="carousel-inner">
          <div className="carousel-item-active" data-bs-interval="5000">
            <Image
              src="/images1.jpg"
              width={800}
              height={200}
              alt="image1"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000">
            <Image
              src="/images2.jpg"
              width={800}
              height={200}
              alt="image2"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000">
            <Image
              src="/images3.jpg"
              width={800}
              height={200}
              alt="image3"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          className="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
        >
          <span
            className="carousel-control-prev-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"
          ></span>
        </button>
        <button
          className="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
        >
          <span
            className="carousel-control-next-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"
          ></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you sahre your code in codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sea-3btrh?file=/components/MyCarousel.js
here it is sir :)

Comment: I finally managed to fix the problem by using react-bootstrap bootstrap library :)

Comment: Sorry, i was pretty occupied, and i was wondering why you are using the normal bootstrap when react-bootstrap is there , anyway good one

Comment: No problem sir, I'm a front-end beginner and trying to learn React. Thanks for your comments!